# Are female voice actors cheaper in Japan?

Tags: voice-acting, japan

There are some anime which have all female characters, and literally, everyone that is voiced is a girl. When there is a guy, he either has a squeaky voice or is actually a girl too.

Is this because female voice actors are cheaper in Japan?

Comment: To clarify:  are you asking why there aren't more male seiyu playing the role of males in specific anime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. But it's way easier for a woman to imitate the voice of a child boy than for a man, and many anime characters are supposed to be pre-voice change.